# the meaning of "... like Vegas"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Following is a paragraph from time.com.
What does “*As a general rule, it’s like Vegas.*” mean?

> While Priess said concerns about information leaks are reasonable given the controversies surrounding the current nominees, he thinks it’s unlikely a candidate would make that mistake: “**As a general rule, it’s like Vegas.**” While legal consequences are “extremely unlikely” in the event a candidate talks, he said there would still be “huge ramifications” politically.
>   Unquote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What happens in Vegas, stays in Vegas](http://www.lasvegas.com/knowthecode/)

The idea is that if you go to Las Vegas, certain things may happen that you might not want to tell your friends, family or spouse about. So anything that happens in Las Vegas, stays there, it is not talked about afterwards.

In your quote, it means that in general, if anything happens or is said that shouldn't happen, or shouldn't be publicly known, you do not talk about it. Simply said, in general, we keep our affairs private.

Comment: This is true, generally, but I think a better summary sentence would be "We keep our affairs private" - they're not making mistakes, necessarily, just having lots of conversations which they wouldn't necessarily want to be made public.

Comment: @MaxWilliams good point, I edited my interpretation of the in-context phrase.